# Use 'Set' for updating arbitrary xdata vectors within the same plot

Tags: matlab

First a little background so its hopefully a bit easier to understand what I'm trying to do:

I am calculating the scattering of photons by a particle. Everything works fine in that part so far. But for visualizing the results I want to do the following: I show a 3d particle that gets 'hit' by photons. The photons are represented by sine waves that first travel straight to the particle where they disappear (this part works fine). At the same moment, when the wave of the first photon 'enters' the particle, a new, scattered (meaning rotated in arbitrary 3d directions) wave has to appear. This works also fine, but only for one scattered wave at a time. To do this I use the plot3 function in combination with the set function to update the wave position within a for loop.

But what I would like to have is the following: while the "wavetrain" of n waves enters the particle, n scattered waves should leave the particle, with the next one starting to emerge as the previous wave pattern has become completely visible. So I see an increasing amount of sine waves flying away from the particle. Each in a different direction with different x,y and z increments.

The problem is that every scattered wave has a different velocity in the x,y and z direction. So for every wave i would need a loop to update the position for every timestep. Furthermore, 'set' only allows me to update vector data for the plot3 function, so only the data of one photon wave at a time.

I'm quite stuck on the problem. So any new input or suggestions are highly appreciated :)

I know the attached code isn't the shortest but that was the shortest I could get it while still showing everything correctly. At the moment the code works fine but the scattered waves are only displayed one at a time (happening in the "emitting of scattered wave"- part near the bottom). I already tried several different ways but i always end up worse.. :/

```
clc
clear all
close all

%-------------------------------------------------------
%Variablen für Animationslänge und Scatter-Frequenz
%-------------------------------------------------------
%Anzahl der Photonen (hat direkten Einfluss auf Animationslänge)
Photons = 3; 
%-------------------------------------------------------
%Background Photowand
%-------------------------------------------------------
a=1.0;
x=-5:0.01:0;
background(1,:) = cosh(x); 
for i =1:80
Background(i,:) = background(:);
end
%--------------------------------------------------------
%Wave Pattern
%--------------------------------------------------------
y_w = (-1*pi:0.01:1*pi);
x_w = 40*ones(length(y_w),1);
x_w(1:length(y_w)) = 0.5*(sin(9*y_w)+sin(10*y_w));
z_w = zeros(length(y_w),1);

xyz_wave = [x_w,y_w',z_w];

%Rotationswinkel für korrekte Darstellung innerhalb des Plots
rotw = 90;

%Rotationsmatrix um Y-Achse
R1 = [cosd(rotw) 0 sind(rotw) ; 0 1 0; -sind(rotw) 0 cosd(rotw)];  

%Rotation um X-Achse
xyz_waveR=xyz_wave*R1;

%Matrix wieder aufspalten in einzelne Vectoren
x_w1 = xyz_waveR(:,1); 
y_w1 = xyz_waveR(:,2);
z_w1 = xyz_waveR(:,3);

%Abhängig von der Anzahl der Photonen wird die Eingangswelle um eine
%weitere Welle verlängert -> Vektor x_w1 wird kopiert und hinten angefügt
y_w2 = reshape(repmat(y_w1',1,Photons)',size(y_w1',1)*1,[]) ;
x_w2 = reshape(repmat(x_w1',1,Photons)',size(x_w1',1)*1,[]) ;
z_w2 = reshape(repmat(z_w1',1,Photons)',size(z_w1',1)*1,[]) ;
d = linspace(-pi*Photons,0,length(y_w2));
%--------------------------------------------------
%coordinates of scatterd photons
x_2r = [0.2823;-0.2565;0.0147];
y_2r = [0.5272; 0.3008; -0.4846];
z_2r = [-0.0756; -0.1863; -0.0930];

%Austrittsvektor wird zunächst mit NaN initialisiert um später mit
%realen Werten zu füllen
x_2rout2(1:length(x_w1),1:Photons)=NaN;
y_2rout2(1:length(x_w1),1:Photons)=NaN;
z_2rout2(1:length(x_w1),1:Photons)=NaN;

for w=1:Photons
 %Calculation of the rotation angles for the scattered wave
    dx(w) = x_2r(w);
    dy(w) = y_2r(w);
    dz(w) = z_2r(w);
    hyp1(w) = sqrt((dy(w)^2)+(dx(w)^2));
    hyp2(w) = sqrt((hyp1(w)^2)+(dz(w)^2));
    alpha(w) = pi-acos(dy(w)/hyp1(w));
    beta(w) = acos(hyp1(w)/hyp2(w));

    %correction of the scattered angles for the rotation of the wave
    %pattern
    if x_2r(w) >=0
        alpha(w)=pi-alpha(w);
    end
    if y_2r(w) >=0 && z_2r(w) <=0
        beta(w)=beta(w)+pi;
    end
    if  y_2r(w) <=0 && z_2r(w) >=0   
        beta(w)=beta(w)+pi;
    end
    if  x_2r(w) >=0 && y_2r(w) >=0 && z_2r(w) >=0
        beta(w)=pi-beta(w);
    end
    if  x_2r(w) >=0 && y_2r(w) <=0 && z_2r(w) >=0
        beta(w)=pi-beta(w)+pi;  
    end
    if  x_2r(w) <=0 && y_2r(w) >=0 && z_2r(w) <=0
        beta(w)=pi-beta(w);
    end
    if  x_2r(w) <=0 && y_2r(w) <=0 && z_2r(w) <=0
        beta(w)=-beta(w); 
    end
    if  x_2r(w) >=0 && y_2r(w) <=0 && z_2r(w) <=0
        beta(w)=beta(w)+pi;
    end
    if  x_2r(w) <=0 && y_2r(w) <=0 && z_2r(w) >=0
        beta(w)=beta(w)+pi; 
    end

    %values used for the shift of the starting position of the scattered
    %wave
    dxx(w)=sin(alpha(w))*pi;
    dyy(w)=cos(alpha(w))*pi;
    dzz(w)=sin(pi-beta(w))*pi;

  %Rotation of the scatterd wave
    R_x = [1 0 0; 0 cos(beta(w)) -sin(beta(w)); 0 sin(beta(w)) cos(beta(w))];
    R_z = [cos(alpha(w)) -sin(alpha(w)) 0; sin(alpha(w)) cos(alpha(w)) 0; 0 0 1 ];

    xyz_wave_1 = xyz_waveR*R_x;
    xyz_wave_2 = xyz_wave_1*R_z;

    %Shift of the starting point of the scattered wave based on the rotation 
    if x_2r(w) >= 0 
         x_2rout(:,w) = xyz_wave_2(:,1)-abs(dxx(w));
    else
         x_2rout(:,w) = xyz_wave_2(:,1)+abs(dxx(w));
    end

    if y_2r(w) >= 0 
        y_2rout(:,w) = xyz_wave_2(:,2)-abs(dyy(w));
    else
        y_2rout(:,w) = xyz_wave_2(:,2)+abs(dyy(w));
    end

    if z_2r(w) >= 0
        z_2rout(:,w) = xyz_wave_2(:,3)-abs(dzz(w));
    else
        z_2rout(:,w) = xyz_wave_2(:,3)+abs(dzz(w));
    end

     if x_2r(w)>=0 && y_2r(w)>=0 && z_2r(w)<=0
     x_2rout(:,w) = xyz_wave_2(:,1)-abs(dxx(w));
     y_2rout(:,w) = xyz_wave_2(:,2)-abs(dyy(w))*0.5;
     z_2rout(:,w) = xyz_wave_2(:,3)+abs(dzz(w));
     end
     if x_2r(w)<=0 && y_2r(w)<=0 && z_2r(w)>=0
      x_2rout(:,w) = xyz_wave_2(:,1)+abs(dxx(w));
      y_2rout(:,w) = xyz_wave_2(:,2)+abs(dyy(w))*0.5;
      z_2rout(:,w) = xyz_wave_2(:,3)-abs(dzz(w));
     end

     %Adding the actual position of the particle to the photon wave
     x_2rout(:,w) = x_2rout(:,w) + 300;
     y_2rout(:,w) = y_2rout(:,w) + 30;
     z_2rout(:,w) = z_2rout(:,w) + 30;

    %scalefunction
     if abs(dy(w)) >= 0.8
    dkk(w) = 11;
    elseif abs(dy(w)) >= 0.95
    dkk(w) = 12;
    elseif abs(dy(w)) <= 0.3
    dkk(w) = 7;
    elseif abs(dy(w)) <= 0.5
    dkk(w) = 8;
    else
    dkk(w) = 10;
    end
end

%-------------------------------------------
%Partikel
%-------------------------------------------
[xs,ys,zs]=sphere(40);
%-------------------------------------------
%Plot
%-------------------------------------------
h_f=figure('color','w');
maximize(h_f);
Ax1=axes;
h_surf = surf(Background,'edgecolor','none','facelighting','gouraud','ambientstrength',0.1);
view(90,0)
colormap(Ax1,gray);
zeta = 0.7;
brighten(zeta)
camlight right 
axis(Ax1,[0 400, 10 75, 2 62])
camzoom(Ax1,2);
axis off
hold on
%----dummyPlots for the wave patterns--------
h_nan = plot3(NaN,NaN,NaN,'LineWidth',1,'color','r');
h_nan2 = plot3(NaN,NaN,NaN,'LineWidth',1,'color','r');

%----Particle--------------------------
h_surf3 = surf(300+xs,30+ys,30+zs);
set(h_surf3,'EdgeColor','none','facecolor','g','facelighting','gouraud','ambientstrength',0.5)
%--------------------------------------
%Zusätzliche Variablen
q = 1;
qq = 1;

dk = 6;
%----------------------

for i = 1 : Photons

pp = 1;
set(h_nan2,'visible','on')

for k = 1:dk:length(x_w)
 vec=ceil((length(x_w2)/(Photons*2*pi))*(0.1*dk));

    if d(length(d))+0.1*k <= 30 && i==1
        set(h_nan,'XData',300+x_w2,'YData',d+0.1*k,'ZData',30+z_w2);

    elseif d(length(d))+0.1*k >= 30 && i == 1  && vec*2*q <= length(x_w2); 
        %let the incomming wave disapear
       x_w2(length(x_w2)-vec*2*q:length(x_w2))=NaN;   
       y_w2(length(x_w2)-vec*2*q:length(x_w2))=NaN;
       z_w2(length(x_w2)-vec*2*q:length(x_w2))=NaN;
        set(h_nan,'XData',300+x_w2,'YData',d+0.1*k,'ZData',30+z_w2);     

        q = q+1;

    end

        if d(length(d))+0.1*k >= 30 && dkk(i)*pp*dk <= length(x_w)  
        %----------------------------------------------------------------
        %----------------------------------------------------------------
        %emitting of scattered wave 
        x_2rout2(1:1+dkk(i)*pp*dk,i)=x_2rout(1:1+dkk(i)*pp*dk,i);
        y_2rout2(1:1+dkk(i)*pp*dk,i)=y_2rout(1:1+dkk(i)*pp*dk,i);
        z_2rout2(1:1+dkk(i)*pp*dk,i)=z_2rout(1:1+dkk(i)*pp*dk,i);
        set(h_nan2,'XData',x_2rout2(:,i)+dx(i)*pp,'YData',y_2rout2(:,i)+dy(i)*pp,'ZData',z_2rout2(:,i)+dz(i)*pp);

        pp = pp + 1;
        qq = pp;
        else 
        set(h_nan2,'XData',x_2rout2(:,i)+dx(i)*qq,'YData',y_2rout2(:,i)+dy(i)*qq,'ZData',z_2rout2(:,i)+dz(i)*qq);
        qq = qq + 3;
        end
        %---------------------------------------------------------------
        %---------------------------------------------------------------
        drawnow 
end
    %Ausblenden der Eingangswelle
    set(h_nan2,'visible','off');
end
```

Comment: Please see: [MCVE]

Comment: Please, note that the first word from MCVE is **Minimal**. Try to make an example that only has the behavior you are trying to fix. That said, cool animation you have there.

Comment: I dont really understand. You want to have multiple scattered waves right? What limits your from having them in that loop? When you plot one..... plot two. Also I am quite sure that you can just change the speed quite easily by just moving it less in each iteration.

Comment: the problem i am facing is that 'set' only allows me to update one vector, so i can only show the movement of one vector at a time, while i really want to show multiple ones

Comment: Why can't you call `set` more than once?